# Database query in Express error: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined

Tags: node.js, express, model, controller, routes

I'm setting up a controller, model, route, and view in my express application.  Modifying my application that was working with just a view, I am getting this error:
Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined

I got it to work with just the pug view and server.js files, but once I added the model/controller/routes, its throwing this error.

```
# server.js
// http://localhost:8099/tasks
var router = express.Router();
var tasksRouter = require('./routes/tasks');
app.use('/tasks', tasksRouter.tasks_list);
```

```
# models\tasks.js
const mysql = require('mysql');

// connection configurations
const mc = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'mysql',
    port: '2001'
});

// connect to database
mc.connect();

module.exports = mc;
```

```
# controllers\tasksController.js
var Tasks = require('../models/tasks');

// Display list of all tasks.
exports.tasks_list = function(req, res, next) {

    mc.query('SELECT * FROM tasks', function (error, results, fields) {
     if (error) throw error;
     //console.log('The solution is: ', results);
      res.render('tasks_list', {
        title: 'Results',
        data: results
      });
    });

};
```

```
#routes\tasks.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Require controller modules.
var tasks_controller = require('../controllers/tasksController');


/// ROUTES ///

// GET request for list of all tasks.
router.get('/tasks', tasks_controller.tasks_list);

module.exports = router;
```

```
#views\tasks_list.pug
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
    table
      for tasks in data
        tr.odd(role='row')
          td #{tasks.id}
          td #{tasks.task}
          td #{tasks.status}
          td.dt-body-right.sorting_1 #{tasks.created_at}
```

I should be shown a page in the browser of the table data parsed into html.  But in my console I'm getting:
c:\ExpressProject4\express-node-rest-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined
    at Function.use (c:\ExpressProject4\express-node-rest-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458:13)
    at Function. (c:\ExpressProject4\express-node-rest-project\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach ()
    at Function.use (c:\ExpressProject4\express-node-rest-project\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:217:7)
    at Object. (c:\ExpressProject4\express-node-rest-project\server.js:34:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subproperty `tasks_list` you are referencing here:

```
app.use('/tasks', tasksRouter.tasks_list);
```

Is not assigned in `tasks/router.js` - you need to either restructure the exported object or change the way it is reference when `require`-d.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  I'm using `tasks_list` to tell the tasksController.js which route to use.

Comment: where is `tasksRouter.tasks_list` being assigned?

Comment: It looks like I should change my server.js to be just `app.use('/tasks', tasksRouter);` however now I don't get an error, but in my browser, when I go to http://localhost:8099/tasks, I get Cannot GET /tasks

Comment: Looking at the [docs for `app.use`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use), I think the `/tasks` path is being defined twice - once in the route handler, and once when you are registering the path. Try changing it to just `app.use(tasksRouter)`

Comment: That was one issue, and probably the main one for this error.  Now I'm getting an `mc is not defined` from the tasksController.js file.  Its because its defined in the model, but not sure how to fix it.